# Rails: reasons why after creating a user and signing out, can't sign in again?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can create a user, and then sign the user out. But when I try to sign in using the parameters that I created the user with, they say invalid parameters.

This is my users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Blog!"
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render "new"
    end
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
  end
end
```

This is my sessions helper methods

```
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def sign_out
    current_user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token))
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
    self.current_user = nil
  end
end
```

And this is my sessions controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
  if user
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    sign_in user
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
  else
    flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
    render "new"
  end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to posts_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
  end
end
```

And I sign in via this form

```
<h1>Log in</h1>
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag :username %>
    <%= text_field_tag :username, params[:username] %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag :password %>
    <%= password_field_tag :password %>
  </p>
  <%= submit_tag "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Is there any reason why when I try to sign in again my user is invalid? My user does have the parameters of password and username. And when created, user is initialized with username, email, password. Thanks!

Comment: What does your user model look like? Specifically your `authenticate` method.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I listened to Hesham's change, then went to check my authenticate, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're authenticating the user with email and password, but your session form has username and password?